# SQLite: fastest way to check if a table has more than x rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is the fastest way to check if a SQLite table has more than 100,000 rows?

---

The test table has 26 columns and 200,000,000 rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100001 )
```

took 0.27 seconds.

The following three needed 12 and a half minutes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table LIMIT 100001
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(Id) >= 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM table
```

Comment: select count(*) from table ?

Comment: SELECT * is not a good idea to get a row count, use an indexed field.

Comment: @ChrisBint: you would need an index on a **not null** column (e.g. a PK) not only "*some index*". Most DBMS I know would automatically use such an index for a `count(*)`. Does your comment imply that SQLite isn't that smart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(*) from (
 select top 100001 ID from T
) x
```

We need to scan an index to answer the query. This at least restricts the index scan to the first 100001 rows. If the table has 1m rows, this saves 90% of the work.

(Using SQL Server syntax here - please translate yourself because I can't do it).

Instead of ID you can choose some indexed column. I don't know if the optimizer can do that itself.

Note, that clever tricks like looking at identity or ID column values do not work in general.

To support the above query, create a dummy column of type `bit` and index it. The index will be very compact and the fastest to scan.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(indexed_column) FROM TableName
```

Now the indexed column part is the important thing, you don't want to do something like counting *, you want to be as specific as possible forcing SQL to use an index that is existing for each row on that table.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT` will bite you, when you have a lot of rows. It works - but you are asking for the fastest way in sqlite.

Use:

`SELECT max(rowid) AS rowcount`

As NoLifeKing pointed out this only works correctly if you do not have any deletions. Otherwise it will get inconsistent and you would have a higher rowcount as is actually in the table.

Check out http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html about the rules, how Sqlite creates rowid.

Comment: Problem with this could be if this is a table where you `DELETE` rows.

Comment: what if i decide to put my rows into the table ordered by descending ids? what if the maximum id of the row is negative ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any indexed column, I think fastest way would be (for N = 100000)

```
select 1 from test1 limit 1 offset 100000;
```

It's because you will get only N + 1 rows. No count, no max.

you can try it here [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7a54e/2)

Comment: Returning all the rows would be much slower than counting them in the engine. Very much slower.

Comment: I don't have SQLite installe here, but sqlfiddle (SQLite.js) shows that offset is much faster than count. I'm no way SQLite expert, it would be great if somebody test it on table with total count much more than N. I could do it later if nobody will

Comment: I was overlooking that you are not returning all rows, just the count. In that case your answer is good because we had the same idea :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from table
```

-- Query optimizer automatically picks the indexed column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (Column) FROM TABLE
```

Ensuring that the column selected is indexed, preferably an INT.

Comment: As had already be pointed out in other answers and comments, `Column` must not be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(indexed_column) >= 100000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM table
```

Shouldn't that do it? Reports 1 if it is over 100.000 and 0 otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from table      
select max(id) from table
```

if table has a primary key id, second on

Comment: count(*) is not good (as mentioned above by ChrisBint) because it cannot use indexes efficiently enough; max(id) is not good, because tables may be fragmented and you cannot assume for all tables that they have incrementing ids